# Casting data array to compatible struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, casting, memory-alignment

I'm in a situation where my code receives data from somewhere beyond my control in the form of a long list of `floats`.

These numbers get distributed to various functions

```
void myfunc(struct floatstruct* fs);
```

that take structs of the following form:

```
struct floatstruct
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
};
```

You get the idea.

I was wondering if there is a way to safely cast the array of floats to `floatstruct` to pass the data directly on to `myfunc`. I can add alignment attributes to `floatstruct` if necessary.

Example of desired behaviour:

```
struct mystruct1
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
};

struct mystruct2
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

extern void myfunc1(mystruct1*);
extern void myfunc2(mystruct2*);

void process_data(float* numbers)
{
    myfunc1((struct mystruct1*)numbers);
    myfunc2((struct mystruct2*)(numbers + 3));
}
```

The ideal solution is surely to change the system. But I'm looking for solutions within the given parameters.

Comment: you would just set the value of each index in arr[] as one of the floats in struct... whats the confusion?

Comment: This is of course what is done at the moment. But there are some new performance constraints. Since the data is already in memory (more or less) in the way I need it to be, I do not wish to copy it again.

Comment: well you cannot cast from a float to a struct, even if it contains floats, it just doesnt work like that

Comment: Besides, I found it generally interesting to know if a struct as above is guaranteed to be laid out in memory like the equivalent array, and if not, whether it can be force to be.

Comment: @that-ru551an-guy Could you point me to the relevant sections of the standard?

Comment: not sure what you mean by relevant sections of standard, but I can tell you that they do have adjacent memory addresses... However, you are casting your essentially struct pointer pointer to a float pointer. You wouldnt try and cast form a type function to a type char would you?

Comment: what you want is to utilize pointers dude

Comment: What is wrong with the `process_data()` as posted? Isn't it the cast you are looking for?

Comment: One thing to make sure with the cast in the call to `myfunc2()` is the order of evaluation of the pointer arithmetic. If you want the 4th `mystruct2` object in the array (starting at `numbers[9]`), rather than the 2nd `mystruct2` object (starting at `numbers[3]`) then make sure the order of evaluation of your pointer arithmetic is correct.

Comment: One more thing, since the packing and alignment of struct members is implementation dependent, but array members are contiguous in memory, make sure you tell the compiler to tightly pack your structure objects (e.g., use the `packed` attribute in `GCC`).

Comment: @ysap dude... READ! its a float ptr that hes trying to cast to struct ptr

Comment: @ysap Thanks, that's what I tried, and it worked. Since the first member of the struct will be aligned, and all further members are packed, I figured it might be safe as well. @ user5254 Do you have any particular safety concerns in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, given your peculiar requirements: ( I say this because 3 new floats here or there will make literally no noticeable difference unless you plan to use this on an arduino or phone or if you plan on having like tens of thousands...)

Anyways:

```
    struct floatstruct
{
    float (*a[3]);
};



{
    int i;
    struct floatstruct aStruct;
    struct floatstruct bStruct;
    float *num = numbers;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (i < 3)
            aStruct.a[i] = num;
        else 
            bStruct.a[i-3] = num;
        num++;
    }

    myfunc1(&aStruct);
    myfunc2(&bStruct);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Union could be what you need:

```
#pragma pack(sizeof(float))
struct mystruct1
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
};

struct mystruct2
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
#pragma pack()

typedef union
{
   mystruct1 struct1;
   mystruct2 struct2;
}structsUnion;

void myfunc1(structsUnion* values)
{
    values->struct1.a; // to access members
}
void myfunc2(structsUnion* values)
{
    values->struct2.x; // to access members
}

void process_data(float* numbers)
{
    myfunc1((structsUnion*)(numbers));
    myfunc2((structsUnion*)(numbers));
}
```

Comment: Unions only allow you to have 1 item in memory at a time. your approach would work for either function, even if you are using the struct with 2 floats and call the one that expects 3. in other words, you will be calling an uninitialized variable, and get garbage

Comment: I know that. Ok. Probably I misunderstood the OP question.